# Unordered lists within ordered lists

Tags: css, list, nested, html-lists, sublist

I am trying to recreate the following, however the subpoints are showing as letters and not numbers once the site CSS is applied.

1. Point 1

   1.1 Point 1.1

   1.2 Point 1.2

   - Sublist for 1.2
   - Another sublist for 1.2

   1.3 Point 1.3

   2. Point 2

Below is an image of how it displays on my site:

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Please include code with your question, showing what you have tried, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to play a bit with css, using counters. Look at the example below:

```css
ol { counter-reset: item; list-style-type: none; }
ol > li:before { content: counters(item, ".") ". "; counter-increment: item }
ul { list-style-type: disc; }
```

```html
<ol>
   <li>Point 1
      <ol type="1">
         <li>Point 1.1</li>
         <li>Point 1.2
            <ul>
               <li>Sublist for 1.2</li>
               <li>Another Sublist for 1.2</li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li>Point 1.3</li>
      </ol>
   </li>
   <li>Point 2</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Hi Matthias. Thank you for this! It looks like my site has a whole load of messy CSS which I apparently don't have access to, but I've managed to make it work with your help. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Follow this html code.

```
<ol>
    <li>Point</li>
    <ol type="a">
        <li>Point 1.1</li>
        <li>Point 1.2
            <ul style="list-style-type:disc">
              <li>Sublist for</li>
              <li>Sublist for</li>
            </ul> 
        </li>
        <li>Point 1.3</li>
    </ol>
    <li>Point 2</li>
 </ol>
```

No need to use any external css styles.

Comment: If I got his question right, he wanted to get rid of the letters

Answer (score 0):

I think, to achieve this with CSS/HTML, you need to use `ul` with some styles and change text inside list

```
<ol>
    <li>Point</li>
    <ul style="list-style:none;padding-left:10px;">
        <li>1.1. Point 1.1</li>
        <li>1.2. Point 1.2
            <ul style="list-style-type:disc">
                <li>Sublist for</li>
                <li>Sublist for</li>
            </ul> 
        </li>
        <li>1.3. Point 1.3</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Point 2</li>
</ol>
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/agdL1tam/

Comment: That is pretty hard to manage, since you always have to write the subpoints manually

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `ol` with `ul`, disable `list-style` and add "custom" list style with `content` of pseudo-element

This is example of ol-sublist of paragraph 1 (https://fiddle.jshell.net/319o3mek/):

HTML

```
<ol>
    <li>Point</li>
    <ul class="sub-ol-1">
        <li>Point 1.1</li>
        <li>Point 1.2
            <ul style="list-style-type:disc">
              <li>Sublist for</li>
              <li>Sublist for</li>
            </ul> 
        </li>
        <li>Point 1.3</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Point 2</li>
</ol>
```

CSS

```
.sub-ol-1 {
  list-style: none;
}

.sub-ol-1 > li {
  position: relative;
}

.sub-ol-1 > li:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: -34px;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: right;
}

.sub-ol-1 > li:nth-child(1):before {content: '1.1.';}
.sub-ol-1 > li:nth-child(2):before {content: '1.2.';}
.sub-ol-1 > li:nth-child(3):before {content: '1.3.';}
.sub-ol-1 > li:nth-child(4):before {content: '1.4.';}
.sub-ol-1 > li:nth-child(5):before {content: '1.5.';}
.sub-ol-1 > li:nth-child(6):before {content: '1.6.';}
.sub-ol-1 > li:nth-child(7):before {content: '1.7.';}
.sub-ol-1 > li:nth-child(8):before {content: '1.8.';}
.sub-ol-1 > li:nth-child(9):before {content: '1.9.';}
.sub-ol-1 > li:nth-child(10):before {content: '1.10.';}
/* more if needed */
```